# Get number only after last string using regex

Tags: java

I have been trying to implement the seperation of string into string and number in java.
As of now following pattern gives me number after string as follows:

```
String[] part = string.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");

Ans: "ABC123" -> ["ABC","123"]
```

But it fails in following scenario

```
"A1BC123" -> 
expected output: ["A1BC","123"]
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need two alternate for non-digit and digit. Also you need to group them separately\

```
((?<=\\d)|(?=\\d))((?<=\\D)|(?=\\D))
```

This will separate all non-digit and digit like you said in your first paragraph, so assuming that what you want this will be the output.

```
"A1BC123" => ["A", "1", "BC", "123"]
```

Comment: @Eritrean Like I said, "like you said in your first paragraph, so assuming that what you want this will be the output."